# mapper in unit test is return null

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I have service method which return mapper to convert entity to DTO when I run the application everything work successfully but when I do unit test the mapper return null.
Also I should mention that, this service is being called by another service "customerDetails" which is under the test.

code snippet, I put comments to describe the problem more :

**customerService**

```
public class customerService {

 private final CustomerMapper customerMapper;

   public Customer customerDetails(int id) {
       CustomerDto customer = getById(id) //here is the problem customer is null
       // rest of the code
     }

  public CustomerDto getById(int id) {
    Optional<Customer> customer =
        this.customerRepository.findCustomerByIdAndIsDeletedFalse(id); //assessment is filled successfully 

      return this.customerMapper.map(customer.get()); //the mapper her return customerDto and accept customer and it return null in unit test only
   }
 }
```

**customerServiceTest**

```
public class CustomerServiceTest {

    @Mock
    private CustomerRepository customerRepository;

    @InjectMocks
    private CustomerService customerService;

    @BeforeEach
    public void createMocks() {
       MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
     }

    @Test
    public void testCustomerDetails() {
       Customer expectedResponse = DummyCustomer.create();
            when(customerRepository.findCustomerByIdAndIsDeletedFalse(actualResponse.getId()).thenReturn(Optional.of(expectedResponse));

              Customer response =   this.CustomerService.customerDetails(expectedResponse.getId());

    }
}
```

Comment: Where is this this.customerMapper is initialized in Class Under Test?

Comment: I edit the question. Is this what you asked?

Comment: Your code is incomplete for both your test and implementation classes. Please provide a minimal woring example or even better the actual code.

Comment: So where s it getting initialized or Injected?

Comment: it is initialized in interface called CustomerMapper

Comment: The question is what creates an instance of CustomerMapper. I'm going to take a guess that you have a constructor that takes it generated by lombok, and that Spring Boot initializes it and puts that in the class without you even knowing. But in your unit test you don't have Spring context running, so it doesn't do that. Am I right?

Comment: M.Deinum I can not write all the code I am not allowed but can you tell me what you want more maybe I can help , I put  code that only related to the problem

Comment: yes yes Deltharis I think you are right I don't write the actual code for mapper I just write the interface and the spring do the rest. I use lombok and mapstruct.

Comment: Why don't you add a very simple version of your code to a repo and link it here? 
Or summarize it (leave out what you're not allowed to show), but give us enough information to be able to reproduce the problem and help you : )

Comment: Ok ,I will delete this question and create another instead of editing it

Answer (score 1):

In actual code Spring handles injection of your mapper for you - but in unit test you don't have spring context set up. In fact you'd have seen the issue earlier if instead of relying on `@InjectMocks` you tried to initialize the service manually.

As to solutions - in test code you can get an instance of your mapper using `org.mapstruct.factory.Mappers.getMapper()` method. Use it and set it in your service under test properly (however you inject your dependencies - via constructor or setter). Or, if you want a "pure" unit test of just one component, mock it.